# Array Subset of Another Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, indexof

If I have an array such as:

```
let arr = ["So 2545", "Cool 1123", "Mos 1999"]
```

that is a subset of a larger array:

```
let largerArr = ["So 2545", "Fun 1023", "Loss 2009", "Cool 1123", "Mos 1999"]
```

How can I determine the index of each matching element in the larger array
so the output would be another array (i.e. let output = [0,3,4])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
const part = ["So 2545", "Cool 1123", "Mos 1999"];
const full = ["So 2545", "Fun 1023", "Loss 2009", "Cool 1123", "Mos 1999"];

const indexes = part.map(v => full.indexOf(v));

console.log(indexes);
```

If you are dealing with large arrays, the overhead of building a lookup table (as suggested in other answers) might become worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) to make a look-up table of indexes, and then you [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) on your `arr` to map each element to an index from the look-up table:

```js
const arr = ["So 2545", "Cool 1123", "Mos 1999"];
const largerArr = ["So 2545", "Fun 1023", "Loss 2009", "Cool 1123", "Mos 1999"];

const lut = largerArr.reduceRight((m, x, i) => m.set(x, i), new Map);
const output = arr.map(elem => lut.get(elem));
console.log(output);
```

The purpose of using `.reduceRight()` is to find the first indexes that the match appears at in the array if the item appears more than once (not the last)